# sqlplus doesn't start on linux 64

Tags: database, linux, oracle11g, sqlplus

I installed, on Mint15 64bit, the Oracle Instant client package 11

Each time I try running sqlplus I get message

```
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

Of course I set correctly the **$ORACLE_HOME**. I tried to set **LANG=us**
Same result.

I tried with instant oracle 12.1, same results !?

Except waving to MariaDb ;) What part is wrong in my install ?

Comment: Did you set `ORACLE_HOME` correctly though?

Comment: Did you `export ORACLE_HOME`,and more importantly for the instant client I think, did you add the same path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Yes it is set correctly. But I thought that ORACLE_HOME was useless with instant client !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Done...
In fact, the sqlplus binary must be in $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus !

Larry... Why did you "hardcode" that ;)

Answer (score 1):

export ORACLE_HOME=/yourpath
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_SID=your sid
sqlplus / as sysdba

Have you added the ORACLE_HOME bin path to the PATH and are you running the sqlplus command with oracle user.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: $ export ORACLE_HOME=/home/snd/instantclient_12_1
$ export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib64

$ sqlplus / as sysdba

Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

Answer (score 0):

The installation instructions at the bottom of [the download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) say:

> Set the library loading path in your environment to the directory in Step 2 ("instantclient"). On many UNIX platforms, LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   is the appropriate environment variable. On Windows, PATH should be
>   used.

You need to set `LD_LIBRARRY_PATH`, not (just) `ORACLE_HOME`. And make sure it's exported, not just set in your current shell.

Comment: If I didn't set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly, I wouldn't get this message. Instead I would have a linker error. And yes ORACLE_HOME is correctly sets

Comment: I think you would. Remember that the instant client has files in different places to the full client; so there is no `bin` or `lib`  (or `lib64`) subdirectory to append to the path.